# copy paste the matched columns from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, loops, import, range, match

I have a question about copy paste specific columns from one worksheet(ws_Copy) to  another(ws_Dest). I need to loop through each column header and match it with the headers in ws_Copy. If it matches, I need to copy the whole column into the ws_Dest with the matched header.

Not sure if my explain is clear or not, here is the sample code:

```
Sub Import_data()
Dim path As String
Dim file As String
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lastcol As Integer
Dim lastrow_ir As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer

path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MACROS").Range("import_path_IRHedge").Value
file = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MACROS").Range("file_IRHedge").Value

'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks(file).Sheets("data_ir_bpv")
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IR Hedge")

'Find last used column in the destination sheet
'Find last row in the copy sheet 
lastcol = wsDest.Range("C:AD").Column
lastrow_ir = wsCopy_ir.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Use the Match function to find the corresponding column to copy paste
For i = 3 To lastcol
    Set Rng1 = wsCopy_ir.Range("C14:AC14")
    m = Application.WorksheetFuntion.Match(wsDest.Cells(1, i).Value, Rng1, 0)
    wsCopy_ir.Range("C14:C & lastrow_ir").Columns(m).Copy
    wsDest.Range("C2").Columns(i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
MsgBox "Data has been imported successfully"
End Sub
```

But the error message "Object doesn't support this property or method" kept showing up in the row:

```
 m = Application.WorksheetFuntion.Match(wsDest.Cells(1, i).Value, Rng1, 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `WorksheetFunction`. You're missing a `c`.

Comment: omg thank you, didnt spot it at all... but still couldn't run the next line, ` wsCopy.Range("C14:C & lastrow_ir").Columns(m).Copy`. the error message is "Method  'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. I just start learning vba, thanks for the help!

Comment: `"C14:C" & lastrow_ir`. Variables should be *outside* the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, corrected it. Do you think my loop is logically correct?

Comment: Another issue: `lastcol = wsDest.Range("C:AD").Column` - this doesn't return what you think it does. It will always be `3`. Use `End(xlToLeft)` to find the last column.

Comment: Coz it is actually not the last column, I need to change the name, I change it to `Lcol = wsDest.Range("C:AD").Columns.Count`, will it work?

Comment: It's not a problem with the name, it's a problem with how you determine the last column.